# Downloading csv from URL

Tags: r

I want to directly download the csv file from given URL = "https://stooq.pl/q/d/l/?s=alr&d1=20190404&d2=20190411&i=d"

When I run this in chrome explorer then I get the csv file with data downloaded. But when I run this with R code I get EMPTY csv file download.

```r
url = "https://stooq.pl/q/d/l/?s=alr&d1=20190404&d2=20190411&i=d"
download.file(url)
```

Expected: file with data
Results: EMPTY FILE `Content type 'text/html' length 0 bytes downloaded 0 bytes`

Comment: please check that URL in quotes
url = "https://stooq.pl/q/d/l/?s=alr&d1=20190404&d2=20190411&i=d"

And there is no file at this URL. May be problem i URL

Comment: looks to me like the url is pointing to an empty file: `curl "https://stooq.pl/q/d/l/?s=alr&d1=20190404&d2=20190411&i=d"` gives nothing..

Comment: when I run https://stooq.pl/q/d/l/?s=alr&d1=20190404&d2=20190411&i=d with chrome explorer then ya will get file "alr_d.csv" downloaded. This is a file with stock prices of polish bank "Alior".

Comment: did you login somewhere on stooq.pl ? your error does not seem reproducible for others.

Comment: no I'm not logged in but oh I see ya must first open the main page https://stooq.pl/ and then open https://stooq.pl/q/d/l/?s=alr&d1=20190404&d2=20190411&i=d ... really strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the main page [stooq.pl](https://stooq.pl) made a trick both from browser and from R. Try this:

```
url <- 'https://stooq.pl/q/d/l/?s=alr&d1=20190404&d2=20190411&i=d/alr_d.csv'

download.file('https://stooq.pl' , 'new.txt')
download.file(url, 'alr_d.csv')
```